# Make a database inaccessible through “sa” user but should be accessible through another user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database `BugTracker` which is accessible from "sa" user.

I have just created new user `AdminBugCatcher`. I have also mapped "BugTracker" database with this user. But this database should not be accessible through "sa" user.

How can we achieve the same ?

I have already tried to unlink this database from "sa" user but getting an error "Drop failed for the User "dbo" ".

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible. I'm not an expert, but I do have about 7 years of experience with sql server, and to the best of my knowledge, sa is system administrator, and you can't block this user from anything.

You can disable the sa login (although I wouldn't recommend it), or better yet, just don't give the sa password to anyone except the system administrator.

For a little bit more information, read [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0be008b8-4cbf-488c-b355-1e8c8a73c5cb/can-i-restrict-access-to-my-database-for-the-sa-user).

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the sa account but you can rename and/or disable it.
Just make sure if you disable the sa account that you have another account with administrator   privileges.

Please refer the below link for DISABLING\RENAMING

http://www.andreas-kraus.net/blog/security-advise-rename-your-sql-server-2005-sa-account/

Answer (score 1):

sa is a member of the SYSADMIN role and this can't be changed. 
All you can do is put a strong password on "sa" and keep it safe.